# Joda - remove seconds, milliseconds from PeriodFormat.getDefault().print()?

Tags: java, jodatime

I have a method like this:

```
public static String getFormattedDateDifference(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate) {
        Period p = new Period(startDate, endDate);
        return PeriodFormat.getDefault().print(p);
    }
```

I'd like to chop off the seconds and milliseconds from printing. How can I do that?

Comment: Use your own formatter instead of the default? See [this SO question for possible guidance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4585883/understanding-joda-time-periodformatter).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you only want it down to minutes, why not just specify the right period type to start with?

```
private static final PeriodType PERIOD_TO_MINUTES = 
     PeriodType.standard().withSecondsRemoved().withMillisRemoved();

public static String getFormattedDateDifference(DateTime startDate,
                                                DateTime endDate) {

    Period p = new Period(startDate, endDate, PERIOD_TO_MINUTES);
    return PeriodFormat.getDefault().print(p);
}
```

I expect that to format in the way you want.

Note that if these are *really* meant to be dates, you should probably use `PeriodType.yearMonthDay()` and specify the values as `LocalDate`. `DateTime` should be used for date and time values, not just dates.

Comment: Wow. Just learning Joda for the first time after experiencing firsthand the horrors of the Java Calendar API. Joda continues to amaze me. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @LuxuryMode: Yes, Joda Time is *much* nicer :)